# Send multiple email rows and multiple product list in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table for products (name, price) with 10 rows and another table for clients(client names and emails) with 50 rows with mysql database. I want to send my product list (10 rows) to my clients that are active.

So that each client will get all the 10 rows of products as one email.
I tried to put the product and client table in a loop, but I can only send one to one email.

Below is my code:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products");
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($sql); 
$mail_body = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
  $id = $row["pdid"];
  $price = $row["price"];
  $product = $row["product"];
  $mail_body = '';
}
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email FROM clients WHERE  type='Active'");
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($sql); 
$email = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
  $email = $row["email"];
  $name = $row["firstname"];
}
$subject = "New products";
$headers  = "From:info@welcare.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$to = $email;
$mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);

if ($mail_result) {     
    echo 'ok';
}
```

The link below shows how to loop multiple product rows for one static email address, but I want to be able to send the email to multiple emails clients  with looping product rows as body of the email all from mysql database table using php.

[Send multiple rows in one email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052775/send-multiple-rows-in-one-email?answertab=active#tab-top)

Can anyone help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the call to `mail` inside the loop that iterates over clients:

```
...
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email FROM clients WHERE type='Active'");
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($sql); 
$subject = "New products";
$headers  = "From:info@welcare.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
   $email = $row["email"];
   $name = $row["firstname"];
   $mail_result = mail($email, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);
}
```

Comment: great answer dude :) appyrently i was searching such code